# getting error using self certificate verification in python ssl

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, urllib3

Getting the following error :

`[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1045)`

I'm using self-signed certificates between many servers, now need to integrate python in the system but unable to verify self-signed certificates.

The code I'm using

```
context = ssl.create_default_context()
context.load_verify_locations("/var/certs.crt")
context.load_cert_chain(certfile=cert_path, keyfile=key_path)
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQ

resp = urllib.request.urlopen(url_string, context=ctx)
```

**var/certs.crt** containing the certificate of the specific server I'm starting an ssl connection with.

**cert_path & key_path** are my own cert and private key to establish 2 way ssl.

Things I've checked :

1.I can see my certs being loaded after **load_cert_chain** in `context.get_ca_certs()`

2.I tried `context.verify_flags |= 0x80000` but it didn't work.

If `ctx.verify_mode = False` then I'm able to connect properly but it will not be secured.

Since the best existing answer on StackOverflow is to use `ctx.verify = False` and it's not the way, I'm hoping this time to find someone who actually fixed it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking in wireshark I saw that python throwing the wrong error. the problem wasn't with the self certificate but was "Certificate Unknown" and the SSL handshake failed.

So it can be done with ssl.CERT_REQ